# AWS's JavaScript SDK Changing Angular.js Delimters

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I am attemtping to implement a file explorer using the Amazon S3 Explorer Plugin from here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-js-s3-explorer/tree/v2-alpha within a Django Project.

The 'placeholders' for the template in the HTML page are the same Django uses so I am getting errors while attempting to render the template with the same code provided in the `index.html` file. When I used Vue a bit ago I remember being able to change the selectors from `{{ }}` to whatever I wanted, how can I do this here?

**This is Angular.js code.**

I have tried to do this here without success:

```
angular.module('aws-js-s3-explorer', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}).factory('SharedService', SharedService)
  .controller('ErrorController', ErrorController)
  .controller('ViewController', ViewController)
  .controller('AddFolderController', AddFolderController)
  .controller('InfoController', InfoController)
  .controller('SettingsController', SettingsController)
  .controller('UploadController', UploadController)
  .controller('TrashController', TrashController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a `config()` block for configuring [`$interpolateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

```
angular.module('aws-js-s3-explorer', [])
  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  }).factory...
```